# Decoding unknown integer position format into more common (lat, lon) pair?

Tags: position, gis

I am getting location data from a web service which looks like this (integer values):

- Latitude: 9188598
- Longitude: 1155331

I know the location real-world location to be:

- Latitude: 63.358523151
- Longitude: 10.378122700

What is the magic mapping between the formats?

Comment: How do you know this? Which web service is it ?

Comment: It is real-time bus data for Trondheim (a city in Norway). I happen to know where this particular bus stop is located (Tiller vgs). :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a beautiful city!  Do you have the WSDL link ?

Comment: Wdsl is http://st.atb.no/InfoTransit/userservices.asmx?WSDL, but you need to get a api key from the bus company (atb.no)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some web mapping sites (Google, OpenStreetMap)
use a simple Spherical Mercator projection, also known as EPSG:900913.

The formulas for converting between lat/long and Spherical
Mercator are listed at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator

Unfortunately, there is a shift of about 100m between your example point
and the results of these formulas.

Maybe this inaccuracy is acceptable?

If not, you have to find more information about the projection.  It will be some variation of Mercator, probably with an ellipsoid different to WGS84 that is used in Spherical Mercator. An ellipsoid contains two measurements of Earth radius (or only one if Earth is being interpreted as a sphere).  WGS84 is 6378137m and 6356752.3142m.  It is also possible that there is a geodetic datum shift required but that is the less likely solution.

Comment: I was thinking that those numbers look like Easting/Northing pairs - as it's a localised service it'd assume that you know the UTM zone that covers Trondheim.

Comment: Great answer! The 100 meter offset could be my fault: picked it on a low resolution map..